# Sort/create columns from a .csv of year-quarters with proportions for categories in an additional column

Tags: python, sorting, datetime, pandas

I am new to python and pandas. I've been learning how to do things online and asking a few experienced programmers. This is the first script I've had to write from scratch, so I apologize for basics I may be missing.  For this task I am using a jupyter shell and python 2.7.

I have a csv file sorted in columns. The columns are sorted by `index, date, title, text, and category`. Only a few of the dates for each month are listed. There are many years. Each text/date is defined by categories that repeat themselves. My objective is to sort the years by quarter, and in each quarter I would like to list the proportions of categories, using pandas and python.

I managed to turn the date strings (`YYYYMMDD`) into date values (`YYYY-MM-DD`) with datetime and create a (sorted from oldest to newest) separate column, and label the rows by quarter (1,2,3,4) in another column, but I need to list the proportions of categories in each quarter, for each year. So ideally I should have year-quarter-category+frequency.

So I just added 2 new columns: one with a sorted `YYYY-MM-DD` format, and each of those days is labeled in the 2nd column with either 1,2,3, or 4. But these columns are not contained in any table, and I haven't been able to create one for them. I think I have to create a new .csv because I've read that I can't write to the existing one. I'm pretty sure I should have grouped the rows by year but I don't know how to go back and fix it. I've been trying to work this out all day, and I don't even know where to start fixing my problems. Any guidance would be immensely appreciated. Thanks for reading. My code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('...somefile.csv', delimiter=',', usecols=('Date','Title','Text','Category'), encoding='utf-8')
for line in df:
    df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d')
    df['DateTime'] = sorted(df['DateTime'])
    df['quarter'] = df['DateTime'].dt.quarter
    print line
```

Comment: You are looking for pandas timegrouper . here is a link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569223/timegrouper-pandas

Comment: @Merlin Thank you, I came across this but I guess I didn't understand how it worked. I thought that it would group months outside of the year I was trying to quarter if there were missing months. That's why I decided to use dt.quarter because it just specifies the quarter of the year the month belongs to. Is that the case?

Comment: Please add sample data  and expected output;so, people can help you.